# jquery found element with .find but unable to apply css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm rather new to jquery and I can't tell why this isn't working. I'm trying to find an element with jquery and then hide it with css.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var thumb = $("entry-content clearfix").find("excerpt-thumb");
    var thumbLink = $(thumb).find("a");
    var thumbImage = $(thumbLink).find("img");
    thumbImage.css("display", "none");
});
```

I've tried debugging a little with an alert() box. Every property I try on any of the variables shows up as undefined (class, name, children, etc.) except for selector which appears to show that it's found the right element -- for example alert(thumb.selector) shows "entry-content clearfix excerpt-thumb."

Would appreciate any help on the matter.
Cheers

Comment: send me the code in fiddle along with your html file

Comment: looks like you are missing the class selector `var thumb = $(".entry-content .clearfix").find(".excerpt-thumb");`

Comment: `$("entry-content clearfix").find("excerpt-thumb")` , `class` or `id`  ??

Comment: you should alert the length to see whether the element is found `alert(thumb.length)`

Comment: @ArunPJohny you seems to be correct

Comment: or even `var thumb = $(".entry-content.clearfix").find(".excerpt-thumb");` if `entry-content` and `clearfix` are in the same element

Comment: Thanks for your comments everyone.

@ArunPJohny I made the changes you said and it's working now.

Comment: A side note - I always use console.log() instead of alert(), the console is much more helpful with debugging, you should try it.

Comment: @pres I wasn't aware I could do that. Thanks! Appreciate it. It was frustrating getting alert() to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to use a **selector** to select what element you need.

- For id = #id
- For class = .class

If they're both classes use the following code:

```
var thumb = $(".entry-content .clearfix").find(".excerpt-thumb");
```

If they're both IDs use the following code:

```
var thumb = $("#entry-content #clearfix").find("#excerpt-thumb");
```

*Other selectors available here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp*

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the class/id selectors in the first var declaration.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var thumb = $(".entry-content .clearfix").find(".excerpt-thumb");
    var thumbLink = $(thumb).find("a");
    var thumbImage = $(thumbLink).find("img");
    thumbImage.css("display", "none");
});
```

Comment: This is what @ArunPJohny has said in comments `5` minutes ago. Didn't you saw that?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works as long as I do ".entry-content.clearfix" (no space.)

Comment: I did, I do share the opinion, so I packed it as an answer and not as a comment, so that the problem can be marked as answered.

Comment: Answers should be posted as answers 

Comment: @Tsel ".entry-content.clearfix" means every element with both selectors, ".entry-content .clearfix" (with space) means any element that has the first OR the second selector

Comment: @kmsdev it was not as answer as there was not enough facts to support it.... even now with the data that is available(except for OP said it is working) there is simply no way to know whether that is an answer... with the given data we can only have guesses... and a more correct action should be to close the question as not clear

Comment: @ArunPJohny I think there was enough facts, and the answer was in your comment (the code is correct, OP just forgot type selectors). SO rules says that we should use comments for comments and answers for answers. If you were not sure, I understand that you use a comment. But answering it is correct because is the valid workaround. It is totally clear.

Comment: I voted for @CruzFolmli's answer, because it's more descriptive and provides sources - and that's kind of the point - provide answers and let the community and the author select the best one. Cheers!